# How to get the region configured on the Android and iPhone using Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

How to get the region configured on the Android and iPhone using Ionic? I am using Ionic 6 with Angular.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [capacitor-native-settings](https://github.com/RaphaelWoude/capacitor-native-settings), to target which section you want to open.

Comment: According to docu it has limitations in regards to iOS. /**
 * Note that the only supported option by Apple is "App".
 * Using other options might break in future iOS versions
 * or have your app rejected from the App Store.
 */. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I have used this in many apps, no problem at all publishing to the app stores.